# Enable and Disable Keyboard return key on demand in iOS

Tags: ios, keyboard, xcode5, uitextfield

I have a UITextField. While user is typing, I am using

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

to validate the string. And if the string is valid I want to enable the return key; if it is not valid I want to disable the return key. Is there a way to do this?

For example the return key would be disabled while the user types the characters in `avai`. Then the return would become enabled after the user finishes typing `avail`. Then the return would be disabled again as user types `availabl`; then become enabled again as user types `available`.

Comment: Do you want to grey-out the return key on the displayed keyboard, or just to ignore the return key so the user has to continue editing?  If the latter, use `textFieldShouldReturn` and return NO.

Comment: @pbasdf I want to gray out the key so user gets visual feedback.

Comment: In which case, I think you will have to use a custom keyboard, though I've never done it myself.  Check the docs for inputView and inputAccessoryView of UIResponder (which UITextField inherits).  Sorry if that's old news...